# Trim beginning and trailing spaces in Code Behind VB

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, trim

I am trying to remove beginning and trailing spaces before my value is entered into the database. I tried the following but with no success and am struggling syntactically.

```
 SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(SqlHelper.Command("dbo.spMYPROC_Insert", SqlHelper.Parameter("@myParameter", e.Values("myParameter"), Trim(Data.SqlDbType.VarChar))))
```

Comment: Your trimming the wrong thing: `Trim(e.Values("myParameter"))`

Comment: Than you that worked!